# Team, Role, and User Criterion defined access to Account feature

Tags: apex, sharing, role-hierarchy

I have a private feature VF page on an Account. Our Account sharing model is Public Read with Edit rights given via Account Teams.

I want to display this VF page only to:

- Account Team Members
- 'Global Access People' defined on their User record
- People up the Role hierarchy from the Account Team

I wanted to check the user's AccountShare access thinking if it was Edit it would show all those people but Role superiors only show READ access even when they actually CAN EDIT (odd).

Is there a simpler way to accomplish my goal? So far it eludes me.

I can get the first two checks (thanks people who have helped) but am not sure how to integrate the Role check:

```
  public class AccountRoleChecker {

  private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public AccountRoleChecker(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }


private Boolean checkUser(){
    if ([select count() from User
            where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() and Admin_Team__c = true] > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ([select count() from AccountTeamMember
            where UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() and AccountId = :sc.getId()] > 0) {
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}


private static Set<ID> getAllSubRoleIds(Set<ID> roleIds) {

    Set<ID> currentRoleIds = new Set<ID>();

    // get all of the roles underneath the passed roles
    for(UserRole userRole :[select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId 
         IN :roleIds AND ParentRoleID != null]) {
        currentRoleIds.add(userRole.Id);
    }

    // go fetch some more rolls!
    if(currentRoleIds.size() > 0) {
        currentRoleIds.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(currentRoleIds));
    }

    return currentRoleIds;
}



}
```

Here trying to use UserRecordAccess:

```
public class AccountUserRecordAccessChecker2{

   public ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public AccountUserRecordAccessChecker2(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }


public boolean getrenderELEMENT(){
    if ([select count() from User
            where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() and Admin_Team__c = true] > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if ([select count() from AccountTeamMember
            where UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() and AccountId = :sc.getId()] > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if([
  SELECT
    MaxAccessLevel,
    RecordId
  FROM
    UserRecordAccess
  WHERE
    UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND
    RecordId = :sc.getId()
  LIMIT 1
  ].size() > 0)
{
    return true;
}
    else {
    return false;
    }

}

}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountUserRecordAccessChecker2"  rendered="{AccountUserRecordAccessChecker.renderELEMENT}" >


    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00OU0000001rGcq" 

    hideonerror="true"

    filter="{column:'Revenue__c.Account__c.Id', operator:'equals', value:'{!Account.Id}'}  " 

    ></analytics:reportChart>



</apex:page>
```

Comment: So to clarify:  Check to see if Current User matches anyone of :::: --- Users on Account team + Users on Global Admin Team + Users in Role HIGHER than anyone on the Account team

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to calculate a given user's "true" access level by running this query:

```
SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess
FROM UserRecordAccess 
WHERE UserId = <some user id> AND
    RecordId = <some record id>
```

This only allows you to check a single user at a time, so it may not always be appropriate, but determining access for the current user is trivial using this pseudo-table.

HasEditAccess will be true if the selected user can edit the record. I'd also look at the [UserRecordAccess](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) documentation for more details.

Comment: I did not know of that object. I want to count, but this isn't working like it does with other objects `private Boolean checkUserAccessLevel(){
    if ([select count () from UserRecordAccess 
            where UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() and HasEditAccess = true and RecordId=:a.id] > 0) {
        return true;
    }`

Comment: @jaw999 No, it doesn't work like normal objects. It has very specific rules, which is why I mentioned the documentation. You don't need to count, though. Just do this: `return [select RecordId, HasEditAccess from userrecordaccess where userid = :userinfo.getuserid() and recordid = :a.id].haseditaccess;`. It will always return exactly one row, so that return statement should suffice.

Comment: OK, i added in the question my try, running through the three checks. Does that look good? Then my VF page would need `  <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountUserRecordAccessChecker" rendered="{!renderELEMENT}" readOnly="TRUE" > ` @sfdcfox

Comment: That would be  rendered="{AccountUserRecordAccessChecker.renderELEMENT}"

Comment: As shown in the second posted attempt, it is not returning TRUE for me logged in as Sys Admin, not on the Account Team, not on the Global Admin team

Comment: @jaw999 Interesting. I'll set up something in my dev org and see if I can replicate the issue.

Comment: @jaw999 It works as expected in my org. I wonder if there's something more subtle going on.

Comment: Could this be a factor? "Using API version 30.0 and later, UserRecordAccess is a foreign key on the records. You can’t filter by or provide the UserId or RecordId fields when using this object as a lookup or foreign key. " thaty was at [https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm]

Comment: No, that's referring to sub queries. It lets you obtain an access level list for all users for a single record.

Comment: So the query : return [select RecordId, HasEditAccess from userrecordaccess where userid = :userinfo.getuserid() and recordid = :sc.getId()].haseditaccess;
 would return true, or the ID?

Comment: It should return true or false (true for an administrator). There might be something else going on here. We might need to take this over to a chat or offline. I suspect there's something else going on here, but I have no idea what off the top of my head. Your code looks right.

Comment: OK, added VF page to main body. Thanks much for help. We can take to chat/offline

Comment: How do I take this offline?  On debug I see no queries even

Comment: I am at a loss.

Comment: one more attempt

Comment: I'm gonna write up a demo tonight when I get home. I'm sorry I've been busy.

Comment: Actually, on latest post it looks like it is working.  I am testing with users who have only the public read only access and the VF page does not render. Still testing.

Comment: I have this in prod and am testing a user added to a global share Read only group, and it renders the VF page, when I only want to to if they have edit... ugh!

Comment: In my sandbox if I login as a person with read only, the chart does not render, though it does not work in prod...

Comment: If you're allowed, can you email me the code you're using? I'd like to help you, and see if we can track down why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, how do I email you?

Comment: @jaw999 It's on my user profile.

Comment: OK, sent, from my developer org yesterday. Thanks!